# Import module could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I've successfully installed "PyPDF2" module and checked it using the command 'pip list'.
yet when I try to import it i receive this message:
'''Import "PyPDF2" could not be resolved'''
[image]

Comment: Try restarting vscode

Answer (score 1):

The version of python that you installed the module in and the version that your IDE is using might be different check what version you installed it in by typing

```bash
pip -VV
```

in your terminal and check in what version your IDE is using (for vs code its usually shown at the bottom left or can be seen in the command pallete by typing **Python: Select Interpreter**)

another reason this could happen is if you are using an IDE like pycharm which by default creates a virtual environment for each project in which case you would need to either install your module from pycharm's terminal or activate the virtual environment and then install in it (docs here show how to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: well I checked the versions and there is NO PROBLEM with them.
and I don't use an IDE, I'm using VS Code text editor.

problem still unsolved :(

Comment: did you check what version vs code is looking at like i said in the post above?
if you didn't find the option its `ctrl + shift + p` to open command pallet and then you type `Python: Select Interpreter` to get the option to choose the actual version (make sure it is same as the one `pip -VV` showed you and if even that doesn't work maybe try `py -m pip install PyPDF2` for windows or `python3 -m pip install PyPDF2` for linux / mac  and then try running your file from the commandline and that should make sure your module is installed to the version you can run from your commandline

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed PyPDF2

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

2. Select the correct interpreter

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGymM.png)

Comment: I did install PyPDF2, and did select the right interpreter, yet, still having this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure that you are using the correct environment and python interpreter. If multiple python versions exist on your computer, use the command to install the PyPDF2 package under the version you need. For example python3:

`py -3 -m pip install PyPDF2`

Another possible reason: Paths are not imported correctly. Please add the following commands in the setting.json file:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths":[
    // The folder path where the custom module is located, and multiple paths can be added (the following is just an example)
    // absolute path
    "c:\\workspace\\pythontest\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages",
    "E:\\myfolder\\homework\\one\\Person_reID_baseline_pytorch-master",
    // relative path
    "./src",
    "./modules" 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem but when I Hover over the problem it showed me quick fixes option{vs code} and I used them and the problem was gone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35816947)